# Wrapper for JComboBox enabling search through Model Elements has error related to Caret

Tags: java, swing, document, jcombobox

first question...

I've read the tutorial at http://www.orbital-computer.de/JComboBox/ and based on that I have made modifications to create a class that you pass an existing JComboBox in order to make it searchable.

I've managed to make the JComboBox modify the results but there seems to be something going on with the caret that I've broken.

Specifically I want any JComboBox passed to this class, to auto-select any existing items in the list that return true for my .indexOf statement.

Code:

```
public class SearchableJComboBox extends PlainDocument {
    JComboBox comboBox;
    ComboBoxModel model;
    JTextComponent editor;
    // flag to indicate if setSelectedItem has been called
    // subsequent calls to remove/insertString should be ignored
    boolean selecting=false;
    boolean hidePopupOnFocusLoss;
    boolean hitBackspace=false;
    boolean hitBackspaceOnSelection;

    public SearchableJComboBox(final JComboBox comboBox) {
        this.comboBox = comboBox;
        model = comboBox.getModel();
        editor = (JTextComponent) comboBox.getEditor().getEditorComponent();
        editor.setDocument(this);
        comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        });
        editor.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if (comboBox.isDisplayable()) comboBox.setPopupVisible(true);
                hitBackspace=false;              
            }
        });
        // Bug 5100422 on Java 1.5: Editable JComboBox won't hide popup when tabbing out
        hidePopupOnFocusLoss=System.getProperty("java.version").startsWith("1.5");
        // Highlight whole text when gaining focus
        editor.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {

            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                // Workaround for Bug 5100422 - Hide Popup on focus loss
                if (hidePopupOnFocusLoss) comboBox.setPopupVisible(false);
            }
        });

        // Handle initially selected object
        Object selected = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
        if (selected!=null) setText(selected.toString());

    }


    void setPrototypeValue(Object value, JList list) {
        comboBox.setPrototypeDisplayValue(value);
        list.setPrototypeCellValue(value);
    }



    JList getListBox() {
        JList listBox;
        try {
            Field field = JComponent.class.getDeclaredField("ui");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            BasicComboBoxUI ui = (BasicComboBoxUI) field.get(comboBox);
            field = BasicComboBoxUI.class.getDeclaredField("listBox");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            listBox = (JList) field.get(ui);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException nsfe) {
            throw new RuntimeException(nsfe);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException iae) {
            throw new RuntimeException(iae);
        }
        return listBox;
    }

    public void remove(int offs, int len) throws BadLocationException {
        // return immediately when selecting an item
        if (selecting) return;
        if (hitBackspace) {
            // user hit backspace => move the selection backwards
            // old item keeps being selected
            if (offs>0) {
                if (hitBackspaceOnSelection) offs--;
            } else {
                // User hit backspace with the cursor positioned on the start => beep
                comboBox.getToolkit().beep(); // when available use: UIManager.getLookAndFeel().provideErrorFeedback(comboBox);
            }

        } else {
            super.remove(offs, len);
        }
    }


    private void setText(String text) {
        try {
            super.remove(0, getLength());
            super.insertString(0, text, null);
        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.toString());
        }
    }


    public void insertString(int offs, String str, AttributeSet a) throws BadLocationException {
        // return immediately when selecting an item
        if (selecting) return;
        // insert the string into the document
        super.insertString(offs, str, a);
        // lookup and select a matching item
        Object item = lookupItem(getText(0, getLength()));
        if (item != null) 
        setSelectedItem(item);
    }

    private void setSelectedItem(Object item) {
        selecting = true;
        model.setSelectedItem(item);
        selecting = false;
    }

    private Object findStringWithin(String pattern) {

        for(int i=0; i<model.getSize();i++)
        {
            if(model.getElementAt(i).toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(pattern.toLowerCase())!=-1)
            return  model.getElementAt(i);  
        }

        return null;
    }



    private Object lookupItem(String pattern) {
       return this.findStringWithin(pattern);
    }


}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean that the caret is broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code and the website you reference.

No where do you include the line from the "curser" section:

```
editor.setCaretPosition(getLength());
```

This causes your caret to get stuck at the beginning, and essentially as you type you over-write the previous characters.

Give it a try ...

Comment: That did the trick, thank you very much! I don't know how I deleted that.